# How do I get column name from a SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any easy way just to get the column names returned from a SQL statement ?

Such as:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM ATable 
 FULL OUTER JOIN BTable b ON a.SOME_KEY = b.SOME_KEY
 FULL OUTER JOIN CTable c ON b.SOME_ID = c.SOME_ID
 FULL OUTER JOIN DTable d ON a.SOME_OTHER_ID = d.SOME_OTHER_ID
 WHERE a.SOME_KEY = @key AND c.SOME_SERIAL_NR = @serialnumber
```

I cannot seem to get

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'table'
```

to work in my current context

Comment: ?? What exactly you are asking, is not clear. The `information_schema` and system tables store information about base tables, views, indexes, etc. Not about arbitrary queries that run.

Comment: Yes that was what i wrote, 1. I wrote what i wanted help with and 2. i wrote what i tried so far.

Comment: OK but what is that is not working? Both your queries are syntactically valid and should return results. What is the problem?

Comment: Well how about this? `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name IN ('ATable','BTable','CTable','DTable')`

Comment: @dwjv sometimes you just want to over-complicate things. So that you miss the solution right in front of you. If you make a short answer i will reward you with the points you so much deserve.

Comment: @Magic-Mouse I'm no glory hog! Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes to see what's right in front of you, we've all been there.

Comment: @dwjv i never took you for a glory hog but i need to close the question and the answer was yours.

Comment: @Magic-Mouse ah, fair enough - answer added.

Comment: @Magic-Mouse Can you explain why you "need to close the question"? It can be bad for you, the site, and other readers if you blindly accept the first answer that comes along. I'm not claiming that my answer is better in this case, but in general, first does not mean best. You asked your question before most of the Western Hemisphere was even awake; there's nothing wrong with leaving your question open for a day or two to make sure you get the best set of answers to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE table_name IN ('ATable','BTable','CTable','DTable')
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this query, for a number of reasons:

```
SELECT 
  [table]  = s.name + N'.' + t.name, 
  [column] = c.name
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE t.name IN (N'ATable', N'BTable', N'CTable', N'DTable');
```

1. You can tell which column comes from which table
2. You can see the schema ([schema is important](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix))
3. You avoid the broken and incomplete `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views - this doesn't cause a problem for this particular query, but [there will be cases where you can't rely on metadata from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)
4. You should be in the habit of always using the `N` prefix on string literals when the underlying data type in `nchar/nvarchar`.
5. You should also get into the habit of [using proper statement terminators](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)

The cons with my solution:

1. It takes a few seconds longer to type
2. It won't run on Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, etc.